# how to do Reduce, filtration and nested array work javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
const merged = [
  [
    {
      _id: "6136096f4255d84bcb4a7144",
      user_id: "5fbfa729fc46a415ce5503a6",
      device_platform: 'ios',
    },
    { user: [Object] }
  ],
  [
    {
      _id: "613609414255d84bcb4a7122",
      user_id: "5fbf6f91aff7f3320a906547",
      device_platform: 'ios',
    },
    { user: [Object] }
  ],
  [
    {
      _id: "613709f49223350dfdaec618",
      user_id: "5fbfa748fc46a415ce5505f1",
      device_platform: 'ios',
    },
    {
      _id: "613609184255d84bcb4a710a",
      user_id: "5fbfa748fc46a415ce5505f1",
      device_platform: 'ios',
    },
    { user: [Object] }
  ]
]

const user_id = ["5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8"];

const { matching, nonMatching } = merged.reduce(
    (acc, userRecord) => {
      userRecord.JSON.Stringify(user._id) &&
      userRecord.JSON.Stringify(user._id).some(_id => user_id.includes(_id))
        ? acc.matching.push(userRecord)
        : acc.nonMatching.push(userRecord);
      return acc;
    },
    { matching: [], nonMatching: [] }
  );
```

How to filter out from nested array is there any way to fix it with this response please guide

user is coming at object it must contain _id for this I used JSON.Stringify() which seems work isn't ?

Thanks

Comment: do you need delete nested array like that [ [ { data } ] ] => [ { data } ]

Comment: it is not quite clear, what exactly you want to filter out from nested arrays, can you, please, share some (valid) input along with expected output?

Comment: user object is like  {
    _id : "5fbfa729fc46a415ce5503a6",
    name : "xys"
}

now if anything match with user._id == user_id it should be in match case otherwise will be in unmatch case currently it is coming [Object] might need to use JSON.Strintify()

Comment: There is no `JSON.Stringify()` — it is [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to process your data structures, you can use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) here. However, you can use `JSON.stringify()` for the full output:

```js
const merged = [
  [
    {
      _id: "6136096f4255d84bcb4a7144",
      user_id: "5fbfa729fc46a415ce5503a6",
      device_platform: 'ios',
    },
    { user: { _id : "5fbfa729fc46a415ce5503a6", name : "xys" } }
  ],
  [
    {
      _id: "613609414255d84bcb4a7122",
      user_id: "5fbf6f91aff7f3320a906547",
      device_platform: 'ios',
    },
    { user: { _id : "5fbfa729fc46a415ce5503a6", name : "xys" } }
  ],
  [
    {
      _id: "613709f49223350dfdaec618",
      user_id: "5fbfa748fc46a415ce5505f1",
      device_platform: 'ios',
    },
    {
      _id: "613609184255d84bcb4a710a",
      user_id: "5fbfa748fc46a415ce5505f1",
      device_platform: 'ios',
    },
    { user: { _id : "5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8", name : "xys" } }
  ]
];

const user_id = ["5fbfa748fc46a415ce5503a8"];

const { matching, nonMatching } = merged.reduce(
    (acc, userRecord) => {
      if (userRecord.some(object => user_id.includes(object?.user?._id))) {
        acc.matching.push(userRecord);
      } else {
        acc.nonMatching.push(userRecord);
      }
      return acc;
    },
    { matching: [], nonMatching: [] }
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(matching, null, '  '));
console.log(JSON.stringify(nonMatching, null, '  '));
```